# Using Cache manifest in a phonegap 'wrapped' app

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a web app (jqmobile) that will be wrapped in Phonegap so that it can be available in the app stores.
What I am having difficulty with is where is the best place to put the html files?  Do I wrap them into  the app, or can I still host those pages on a remote server ? 
If I decide to update an image/element in one of my html pages, will I then have to force users to 'update' their app in the stores ?? I don't want to have to do that if possible.

Also, This app needs to support 'offline' mode, but I have heard that cache manifest is not supported in a phonegap IOS app ? 
Can anyone knowledgable out there give me some direction on this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could load an "external page" , but I don't think apple will allow it to be put in the appstore.

Other way is to pull in images using Ajax/XHR and store them locally in your webapp. Does need some work though to have it working properly as you need to work with binary blobs. In this way you can update existing local resources and keep your app fast.

Other Other way is again use XHR/AJAX just too pull the emote images to be placed in your local web app. I think you'd be OK with this and Apple too. It will be slower and you need to handle that, or else users will see empty places or loading images in your app.

Phonegp wraps all your resources in the App.